# How to create new Python methods by a loop? (Attempting results in all methods acting like the one last defined)

Tags: python, types, lambda, metaprogramming

I'm looking into generating a Python class dynamically from data.
(The purpose is to let users specify some software tests in a simple file, without knowing any Python).
I have run into an effect I did not expect;
as a toy example to quickly check that I can create methods according to a naming scheme I did the following:

```
import unittest

attrdict = {}
for i in range(3):
    attrdict["test%s"%i]= types.MethodType(lambda self: i)
attrdict["runTest"]=lambda self: [eval("self.test%s()"%i) for i in range(3)]
dynTC = type('dynTC', (unittest.TestCase,), attrdict )
```

now when I execute

```
dynTC().runTest()
```

... I would expect

```
[0,1,2]
```

as output, but the actual result is

```
[2,2,2]
```

I would expect the lambda definitions to bind a deep copy of the loop index, since it is just a number rather than a more complex structure, but clearly there's stuff going on here that I don't understand.

I have a feeling this may be a common 'gotcha' for new Python programmers, but all the terms I can think of to describe the problem are so generic that my searches only return a deluge of unrelated answers.

Could you please explain to me what is happening here instead of what I expected, and preferably also what I should have done to create the desired effect of several /different/ methods.

Comment: The call to types.MethodType( ... ) was actually not part of the initial test and as it stands that call lacks parameters. Sorry! I pasted a slightly different stage of the workflow than I intended. Since it has already been quoted in the answer and did not hurt the main point of the question I'll just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line...

```
attrdict["test%s"%i]= types.MethodType(lambda self: i)
```

When you define a `lambda` that references a variable which isn't one of its arguments, the variable will be resolved from the scope in which the `lambda` was defined at the point when it's actually called, so you'll always get whatever the current value of `i` is, rather than the value of `i` at the point when you defined the `lambda`.

In your case, the value of `i` will end up as `2` after the `for i in range(3)` loop completes, so you need to create a closure to bind `i` to a specific value when creating the `lambda`, by changing the line to...

```
attrdict["test%s"%i]= types.MethodType(lambda self, i=i: i)
```

Comment: "the variable will be resolved from the calling scope when the lambda is called" Not true. The scope where it is called might not have a variable `i` or might have a different one. Instead, it will always refer to the variable from the original scope.

Comment: That gives me pretty good idea of what's going on and the terminology to search effectively for more. Thank you!

Comment: @newacct Good point. Updated answer.